Dispersion of random walk with scaled step sizes
Let $Y_j$ be a sequence of independent Gaussian random variables with mean zero and unit variance ($\mathbb{E} Y_j = 0$ and $\mathbb{E} Y_j^2 = 1$) and let $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\to [1,2]$.
We define the random variable $X_k$ so that $X_0=0$ and
$$
X_N = \sum_{j=1}^N \sigma(X_{j-1}) Y_j.
$$
It is not so hard to show that $N \leq \mathbb{E} X_N^2 \leq 4N$.  I would like to know whether one can show the anticoncentration bound
$$
\mathbb{P}( X_N \in [-1,1]) \leq C N^{-1/2},
$$
with a constant $C$ independent of the function $\sigma$.  More generally, I'd like to know if the probability density function of $X_N$ is bounded by $CN^{-1/2}$ (or $CN^{-d/2}$ in a $d$-dimensional generalization).
As an aside, this seems related to the question of $L^1\to L^\infty$ bounds for the variable coefficient parabolic PDE
$$
\partial_t u = \nabla \cdot (a(x) \nabla u),
$$
which can be done elegantly with Nash's argument.   In this case however (a naive translation of) Nash's argument fails because (1) there isn't an integration by parts formula and (2) the operator mapping the density of $X_{N-1}$ to the density of $X_N$ is not self-adjoint.

Maybe I am missing somehitng basic, but since $\sigma$ only ever takes values in $[1,2]$, it seems easy to show that $\mathbb{P}( X_N \in [-1,1]) \leq \mathbb{P}( S_N \in [-1,1])$ where $S_N = \sum_{j=1}^N Y_j$. And since $S_N \sim N(0, \sqrt{N})$, the inequality seems trivial. Or did I misunderstand the question?

The comparison you claim is what I am unable to prove.  For example if you choose an interval other than $[-1,1]$ (perhaps $[x-1,x+1]$ where $x = 10\sqrt{N}$) your proposed inequality fails if $\sigma=2$.

You are right, I forgot to take into account the correlations induced by using $X_{j-1}$ as an argument to $\sigma$. Indeed, I can choose $\sigma$ such that the inequality does not hold.

$$\mathbb{E} X_N^2 \sim N$$ What does that mean? Are you using the letter $N$ for two different things in this expression? I'm tempted to construed${}\sim N$ as "is normally distributed" (i.e. Gaussian) but, to say the least, that doesn't seem right.

Ah, my bad with the sloppy notation.  I intended $cN \leq \mathbb{E} X_N^2 \leq CN$.  (Indeed, one can take $c=1$ and $C=4$).  Hopefully now the question is a little more clear.

If you allow σ
to also depend on j
, then the claim is false; See (for continuous time) arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3068 and for discrete time (but with bounded increments, which should not change much) arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2402. This shows that time-change ideas and embedding into Brownian motion are ill-suited for this problem. I am not sure yet what happens if σ
is not allowed to depend on j
.

Thank you very much for the reference.  I am surprised to find out that the exponent can change if $\sigma$ depends on $j$ (and I agree that the bounded increments shouldn't change much).  That said I do still think that my proposed estimate may still hold when $\sigma$ doesn't depend on $j$ because of the analogy with the continuous time setting --- when $\sigma$ is time independent this holds and otherwise your reference shows that the claim fails.

I also think it should be true, but did not have time to think about it.  I do think that your analogy should not be to the operator $\nabla a(x)\nabla$ (which has local drift!)  but rather to $a(x)\Delta$. Indeed, the first operator corresponds to the so called random conductance model (and then the result, at least for increment $\pm 1$) is true by estimates of Delmotte, for example. The second model is the so called "balanced case" and I am not sure was done.

In one dimension, I think that you can imbed in a Brownian motion, and then time change, to convert your process into a Brownian motion.  Your original process is this Brownian motion stopped sometime between N and 4N. You can try and bound the probability of a stopped Brownian motion being in that interval with stopping time taking values in N,4N. It seems clear that the max over all stopping is achieved by stopping immediately if you are in interval at time N or else going until you hit that interval and stopping.  This can be calculated, although I have not done it, and I think it is probably the magnitude you are looking for.

Does the arcsine law imply that the Brownian motion hits zero (and thereby any interval containing zero) between $N$ and $4N$ with constant probability? If so, does that imply that the worst-case stopping time you describe would stop in the interval with constant probability?

I agree with Ziv.  The probability that $B_N > 0$ and $B_{4N} <0$ is bounded below from a constant.  For example there is a constant probability that $0<B_N<\sqrt{N}$, and then a constant probability that $B_{4N}-B_N < -\sqrt{N}$ ($B_{4N}-B_N$ being just another independent Gaussian).

If you allow $\sigma$ to also depend on $j$, then the claim is false; See (for continuous time) https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3068 and for discrete time (but with bounded increments, which should not change much) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2402. This shows that time-change ideas and embedding into Brownian motion are ill-suited for this problem. I am not sure yet what happens if $\sigma$ is not allowed to depend on $j$.
